# Customising React-Bootstrap vs Bootstrap in project

Tags: bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I had a question about customising React-Bootstrap components.

I have a simple page with 3 columns as below. I want the middle column to be wider than the first and third columns.

Currently, I am using the react component Col, and using className = "col-6"

Is this the right way of doing this?
Is there another (correct) way of customising React-bootstrap components?

Thanks

```
import { Container, Row, Col } from "@/components/bootstrap";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <Container fluid>
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <UserCard user_name="Test 1"></UserCard>
        </Col>
        <Col className = "col-6" >
          <UserCard user_name="Test 2 "></UserCard>
        </Col>
        <Col>
          <UserCard user_name="Test 3"></UserCard>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a class is fine but if you want to do it the React (correct) way you should use it like shown in the [React Bootstrap Docs](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/docs/layout/grid#setting-one-column-width). So you should use this instead:

```html
<Col xs={6}>
    ...
</Col>
```

Comment: Thanks. 

So is React Bootstrap customisation essentially done using properties, whilst in bootstrap its done using classes?

and if I wanted to customise beyond whats available in the doc, I would then use the bootstrap classes? or would I customise my own css style in the .css file?

Comment: Either way the class will be set the only difference is that in React the component will handle it for you. If you want to customize it beyond whats possible it's up to you or your use case e.g. if you want another background for the `col` it's more convenient to just apply another class like `bg-primary` on the other hand if you want to customize the behaviour of the col class then it would be better to do that in your stylesheet. Btw if you want to unleash the full potential of Bootstrap you should consider using SASS/SCSS.